# Chronos docker Job scheduling thru Mesos

Tags: docker, mesos, mesos-chronos

I am using Apache Chronos for job scheduling. My job is a simple Docker Job which executes some java code and then exits by calling System.exit(0).

The job is scheduled to run every 30 mins and I see the status code as "Exited (0) 2 minutes ago"  by executing the following command.

```
docker ps -a


    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND    CREATED      
                                                                                           STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
    789ec59e32442        docker-test:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'java -ja"   2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                           mesos-05fb536b-asdff-3d634c4ed860-S1.be003d0e-7701-4020-84be-234643565244
```

But, When i check the metrics.chronos table, the status message is "**Container exited with status 125 [internal state: TASK_FAILED]**"

I see the status as TASK_FAILED in mesos logs. Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: What happens if you run docker container without scheduling it by Apache Chronos?

Comment: It runs without any issues and when i tried "echo $?", it returns 0.

Comment: It seems related to MESOS-2346 bug - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2346

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using 1.0.3 mesos. I may need to update the mesos version as the fix version is available in 1.1.0.

Comment: Issue is still there even after upgrading mesos to 1.2.1.